# How do you extend a class with type parameters while enforcing a specific type?

Tags: java, generics, collections

I want to extend JGraphT's DirectedAcyclicGraph class with signature `public class DirectedAcyclicGraph<V,E> extends AbstractBaseGraph<V,E> implements Iterable<V>` to create a FamilyGraph class where vertices are always of type Person. This would allow me to write methods such as:

```
public List<Person> getMothers(final Person person) {
        return getAncestors(person).stream().filter(p -> p.getSex() == Sex.FEMALE).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

I tried `public class FamilyGraph<Person, E> extends DirectedAcyclicGraph<V, E>`, but that seemed like it didn't leverage the Person class I had.

Comment: In your class declaration `public class FamilyGraph<Person, E>` the `Person` part is just a generic placeholder just like `E` and not referring to any class. If you want to extend a class and have a generic type always be a specific class in the subclass you need to declare the subclass with that 1 parameter less and put the concrete class in the extends syntax: `public class FamilyGraph<E> extends DirectedAcyclicGraph<Person, E>`. After all your new class only needs one generic parameter as the other one is fixed to a concrete class and not variable.